# Jenkins how to publish phpDox

Tags: php, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, phpdoc

Is there a way to publish the results from having phpDox run in a Jenkins build? See http://jenkins-php.org/ for information on phpDox. Is there a better alternative for Jenkins than phpDox? If so is it easy to setup and install?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, phpDox documentation is rendered as HTML, so you could use the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) for Jenkins to publish it.